# Limiting the WordPress feed to only a certain limit of characters

Tags: php, rss

I have a WordPress installation that sometimes uses long and lengthy posts delimited by the `<!--more-->` tag. However on my RSS feeds, the entire post is shown.

Is there a way, aside from custom tags, to delimit how much is shown in a WordPress Feed or just show enough until the "More" tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select between `Full text` and `Summary` in the *Reading* settings:

[image: settings menu]

[image: settings]

If you select the `Summary`, then

**a)** To control the number of words in the feed summary you can use:

```
add_filter('excerpt_length','custom_excerpt_length'); 
function custom_excerpt_length( $num_words ){
    return 30; // number of words to show
}
```

The default number of words in the summary is `55`.

**b)** If you want to use  `<!--more-->` in the post content to define the feed summary, you can use the following:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'custom_content_feed' );
function custom_content_feed( $content ){
    if( is_feed() ){
        // <!--more--> used in the post content: 
        if( strpos( $content, '<span id="more-') !== FALSE ){
            // remove the excerpt length limit
            add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_long_excerpt_length' ); 
            // get the content before <!--more-->
            $content = stristr( $content, '<span id="more-', TRUE );
            // add the default 'read more' symbols at the end:
            $excerpt_more = apply_filters( 'excerpt_more', ' ' . '[&hellip;]' );
            $content .= $excerpt_more;
         }
    }
    return $content;
}
function custom_long_excerpt_length( $num_words ){
    return 99999;
}
```

**c)**  You can also use a) and b) together.